# John the ripper passwd file format with salt not working

Tags: security, brute-force, cracking

I'm trying test password strength in one of ours ecommerce sites. Im using john the ripper to brute-force a password file.  The algorihtm used by php is:

```
$hash = md5($salt . $pass)
```

No other transformation is performed nor in the $salt or in the pass, I've manually checked one example. I've found in the documentation that the subformat that goes with the algorithm is dynamic_4. The problem is that passwd file format as written in documentation, doesn't seems to work, John is unable to load the hashes, this is the format that ive used:

```
// user:$dynamic_4$hash$salt
 emi:$dynamic_4$83a3f08cfb2d9d0bac5d1a1619d8b7dd$Z3MkG2FZsaoV9EDCpmSRWvgANQAeXOeN7oadrAugu0rKEvfKqoNj6D9a
```

Ive tried to change the salt for the hash but still nothing

Ive tryed the following parameters combination

```
john --single passwd
john --format=dynamic_4 --single passwd
john --subformat=dynamic_4 --single passwd
john --format=md5 --single passwd
john --format=raw-md5 --single passwd
```

Thanks for the replies

Comment: A question possibly better suited on [security.se].

Comment: Thx for the reply, Ive posted it already.

Comment: the question has been answered http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42720/john-the-ripper-passwd-file-format-with-salt-not-working

Comment: You should delete this question then. For future reference, the same question shouldn't be asked on multiple sites - you should rather have flagged it for migration or deleted it when you asked it there.